# AngularJs not compiling

Tags: angularjs

I created a basic AngularJS app and it's not displaying the values on the live site declared on the controller.

The live site displays the expressions written on the controller file instead.

ie. - It displays:

{{ title }}
{{ paragraph }}

Instead of:

First Angular Title
First Angular Paragraph

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Angular Application</title>
      <script src="js/shared/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="mainApp">

    <div ng-controller="MainController">

      <h1> {{ title }} </h1>
      <p> {{ paragraph }}<p>

    </div>

    <!-- Modules -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script src="js/controllers/MainController.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

MainController.js

```
app.controller("MainController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.title = "First Angular Title";
    $scope.paragraph = "First Angular Paragraph";
}]);
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module("mainApp", []);
```

- I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'm completely new to this. I appreciate any help. Thanks for your time.

Comment: check your browser's console for errors

Comment: Here is a JS fiddle of this that works fine https://jsfiddle.net/ggrs24rs/, please post your browser errors...

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularj angular.js:4957
s.org/1.6.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=mainApp&p1=Error%3A…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2F
libs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A201)
at angular.js:88
    at angular.js:4957
    at p (angular.js:410)
    at g (angular.js:4917)
    at hb (angular.js:4839)
    at c (angular.js:1949)
    at Uc (angular.js:1970)
    at we (angular.js:1855)
    at angular.js:33884
    at HTMLDocument.b (angular.js:3468)

Comment: I get this error when I'm including each file individually but it runs fine when I run the code as written below. Interesting...

Comment: Another interesting observation I found was that it works on the latest Safari browser without a problem but not the latest Chrome browser.

Comment: Try to import your JS code in the `<head>` section (but after importing angularjs)

Comment: I tried that. It won't work. I think this is a browser issue that needs to be modified on Google's end.

Answer (score -1):

I have included the angular  from cdn and updated the inline script the same working. please verify included files are loading properly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Angular Application</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="mainApp">

    <div ng-controller="MainController">

      <h1> {{ title }} </h1>
      <p> {{ paragraph }}<p>

    </div>

    <!-- Modules -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module("mainApp", []);

    app.controller("MainController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.title = "First Angular Title";
        $scope.paragraph = "First Angular Paragraph";
    }]);
    </script>


  </body>
</html>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I verified the code above and it works perfectly fine without any console errors. However, I reverted back to including the app.js and MainController.js seperately and I did receive a console error.

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularj angular.js:4957
s.org/1.6.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=mainApp&p1=Error%3A…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2F
libs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A201)
at angular.js:88
    at angular.js:4957
    at p (angular.js:410)
    at g (angular.js:4917)
    at hb (angular.js:4839)
    at c (angular.js:1949)
    at Uc (angular.js:1970)
    at we (angular.js:1855)
    at angular.js:33884
    at HTMLDocument.b (angular.js:3468)

Comment: Another interesting observation I found was that it works on the latest Safari browser without a problem but not the latest Chrome browser.

Comment: Please verify the view source and check all the included files are loaded properly.